# Discharge Air Temperature

Tags: hvac

What is the role of Discharge Air temperature in HVAC?
How does it differ from Supply Air Temp and Return Air Temp?
How does it impact energy consumption and cost

Comment: This sounds like a homework question.  Have you tried reading your text book?

Comment: I am new to HVAC, and not into HVAC domain, i need to understand this terms to apply it for my project work which utilizes these DAT and temp values. If you can point me to Textbook link would be great

Comment: If you can only explain me the role of discharge Air temperature, would be great

Comment: The tempatures are not what affects the efficiency as much as the system design. Measuring the temps can give an indication of how well the unit is cooling for a given volume of air, reduce the air flow and the temp drops. The more efficient the system the less energy it consumes but some systems work by not cooling the airstream as much as others to prevent cold areas but moving more air. There are pros and cons to both designs but the efficiency of a system is what you want to focus on and the total cooling capability described in tons.

Comment: @EdBeal : What is the role of Discharge Air Temperature in Cooling/Heating of a coil/unit

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds like a homework question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Return Air Temperature** is the temperature of the air just before the evaporator/heat exchanger.
- **Supply Air Temperature** is the temperature of the air just after the evaporator/heat exchanger.
- **Discharge Air Temperature** is the temperature of the air exiting the registers (vents).

*Discharge air temperature* should be as close to *supply air temperature*, otherwise you're gaining/losing heat as the air travels through the ducts.